# Unable to assign values for strings when read data from file

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a config.txt file where I'm storing the configurations needed to generate some records and I want to read the config values through C code and assign the parameter values to some variables. For integers and floats the variables are assigned correctly but for string types everytime the loop runs all the string variables are getting updated instead of one particular.

Contents of config.

`TIME_LIMIT=2
ING_IP=45.45.45.45
TIMEZONE=GMT+05:30-India`

```
    const char* timeZone = "GMT+09:00-Tokyo";
    const char* ingIp = "null";
    int timeLimit = 0;

    char *configFileName = argv[++i];

    FILE *configFileHandle = fopen(configFileName, "r");

    char * line = NULL;

    // if (( fgets(line, 500, configFileHandle)) != NULL){
    //     puts(line);
    // }

    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, configFileHandle)) != -1) {

        printf("Line: %s\n", line);
        char *parameter = strtok(line, "=");
        char *value = strtok(NULL, "=");


        char *ptr;
        if( (ptr = strchr(value, '\n')) != NULL)
            *ptr = '\0';

        if( (ptr = strchr(value, '\r')) != NULL)
            *ptr = '\0';

        if ( strcmp(parameter, "TIME_LIMIT") == 0 ) {
            timeLimit = atoi(value);
        }else if ( strcmp(parameter, "TIMEZONE") == 0 ) {
            timeZone = value;
        }else if ( strcmp(parameter, "ING_IP") == 0 ) {
            ingIp = value;
        }
    }
```

The results I'm getting is on each iteration timeZone value is getting overwritten by the latest value of ingIp. I want to assign ingIp = "45.45.45.45" and timeZone = "GMT+05:30-India". For timeLimit the value is getting assigned properly.

Comment: `timeZone = value;` does not assign (copy) a token from the input string, only its pointer. So when you read another string, the data is overwitten. You would need something like `strdup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
timeZone = value;
```

Here you are not copying the contents, instead you are making `timeZone` to point to `value`. Thus `timeZone` will be pointing to latest contents stored in `value`.

What you can do is copy the contents instead of pointer assignment.

Using `strdup`.

```
   timeZone = strdup(value);
```

Or

```
   timeZone = malloc(strlen(value)+1);
   strcpy(timeZone, value);
```

Comment: I think the main problem is not that `value` is local to the loop, but that `value` is the result of `strtok` and probably points somewhere into `line` which is passed to `strtok`. The contents of `line` gets overwritten by `getline` in every loop cycle. In any case using `strdup` will help.

Comment: In my case `strdup` worked as expected and `strcpy` didn't worked because, it failed to convert timeZone from const char* to char*. `strdup` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of direct pointer assignment you should either declare a static buffers and use `strcpy` with them or use `strdup` (and **not forget** to free the memory after it's not needed)

Comment: The memory allocated by `strdup` should not be freed _on every iteration_ but only when `timeZone` and `ingIp` are no longer needed.